# R and mschart: Sorting categories of barchart ratings by user-specified, instead of alphabetical order

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend, mschart

I've been developing a stacked barchart using mschart, and have a couple adjustments I cannot seem to figure out. For the following chart, I need the order of ratings to be Excellent>Very Good>Good>Fair>Poor, whereas they are alphabetical instead.

Also, I need the bars sorted by the highest value of 'Excellent' on top, lowest on bottom:
[image]

My dataset looks like this:

[image]

My code is currently like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(officer)
library(mschart)

# testing mschart barcharts in Word--------------------------------------------

R_POPS_testdataset_forstackedbars <- read_csv("R-POPS testdataset forstackedbars.csv")
RPOPS_ESUtheme <- mschart_theme(axis_text_x = fp_text(color="#808080", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)", font.size = 9), 
                                grid_major_line = fp_border(width=0), grid_minor_line = fp_border(width=0),
                                main_title = fp_text(color="#808080", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)", font.size = 11),
                                legend_text = fp_text(color="#808080", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)", font.size = 9),
                                legend_position = "t")
chart_02 <- ms_barchart(data = as.data.frame(R_POPS_testdataset_forstackedbars), x = "Variable_name", y = "Rating_prop", group = "Rating")
fp_text_settings <- list(
    "Excellent" = fp_text(font.size = 8, color = "white", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)"),
    "Good" = fp_text(font.size = 8, color = "white", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)"),
    "Very Good" = fp_text(font.size = 8, color = "white", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)"),
    "Poor" = fp_text(font.size = 8, color = "white", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)"),
    "Fair" = fp_text(font.size = 8, color = "white", font.family = "Franklin Gothic Medium Cond (Body)")
)
chart_02 <- as_bar_stack(chart_02, percent=TRUE, gap_width = 30, dir="horizontal")
chart_02 <- chart_data_labels(chart_02, show_val = TRUE, num_fmt="0%")
chart_02 <- chart_labels_text(chart_02, values = fp_text_settings)
chart_02 <- chart_data_fill(chart_02, values = c("Excellent" = "#275E6B", "Very Good" = "#4AAAC4", "Good" = "#8CD4E5", "Fair" = "#F7963D", "Poor" = "#BE2327"))
chart_02 <- chart_labels(chart_02, title="Program Organization: Overall Effectiveness", xlab="",ylab="")
chart_02 <- chart_ax_y(chart_02, display=FALSE)
chart_02 <- chart_ax_x(chart_02, major_tick_mark = "none", minor_tick_mark = "none")
chart_02 <- set_theme(chart_02, RPOPS_ESUtheme)

doc02 <- read_docx(path = "R-POPS Evaluation_Program Report Template.docx")
doc02 <- body_add_chart(doc02, chart=chart_02, height=2.75, width=6.5)
doc03 <- print(doc02, target = "R-POPS Evaluation_Program Report Template.docx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, but with the x-axis rather thna the grouping order so I reached out to the R mschart library developers. Here is the [github](https://github.com/ardata-fr/mschart/issues/72) exchange which I think would be helpful for anyone trying to figure out how to sort x-axis or grouping

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).